# If two object that have the same mass are dropped at the same time but at different heights, which will reach the ground first?

Tags: gravity

I tried to do it but every time I drop two of the balls, I can’t tell which one hit the floor first.

Comment: What do you think it would fall first, if you throw a ball from an airplane or from close the floor?

Comment: Make a movie and watch in slow motion.

Comment: Two cars $\,A\:$ (left) and $\,B\:$ (right) apart by a distance $\,d\,$ start moving simultaneously from rest to the right on the line joining them with common acceleration $\,a\,$. Which car will reach first at a distance $\,L\,$ to the right of $\,B\:$??? Why do you confuse your question with masses, gravity, heights etc ???

Comment: You probably can't tell because the difference in heights you used was too small to discern the difference.

Answer (score 2):

The time $t$ it takes an object to fall to the ground from the height $h$ on earth is
$$t=\sqrt{\frac{2h}{g}}$$
With $g\approx constant\approx9.81\frac{m}{s^2}$
As you can see, **as you increase the height, the time also increases.**

For a height of $1m$ it takes about $0.45s$. For a height of $2m$ it takes about $0.63s$

To make this more obvious, you could try increasing the height difference. Maybe get a friend to drop a ball out of a window at the same time you drop it from a much smaller height. If you can measure how long it took for the ball to hit the ground you could even calculate how high the window is, since:

$$h=g \cdot t^2 \cdot \frac{1}{2}$$

Answer (score 0):

While your question is rather straight forward, if you know the math which is involved (see NiveaNutellas answer), you *probably* found out a rather interesting thing: If you drop two identical objects, the first object from 0.2m and the second from 1m, it will be rather simple to tell, which one reaches the floor first. However, if you drop the first object from 1m and the second from 1.8m it's hard to tell which object reaches the floor first. This its true, although in both examples the second object is 0.8m above the ground, when the first one reaches the ground.

The reason why it's much harder to tell the difference in the second example than in the first one is the velocity of the second object:

- In my first example (0.2m and 1m) the second object is still "slow" when the first one reaches the ground. Therefore, it takes a longer time to pass the 0.8m.
- In contrast, in my second example (1m and 1.8m) the second object is "fast". Thus, it takes only "a little bit" of time to pass the 0.8m.

Hope this gives you some intuition.

Answer (score 0):

Newtonian Mechanics give us some equations that would described mathematically that experience of yours.

So, when you drop a ball of mass $m$, the ball will only be acted by the gravity force (we are making the assumption that the air drag is negligible). So the ball will experience an acceleration $g$ downwards.

By Newton’s Second Law we come with the equation of motion:

$$y(t) = h - v*t - (1/2)*g*t^2$$

Where $h$ is the initial height, $v$ is the (negative, because it’s downward) velocity, $t$ the time, $y$ the height at some instant $t$.

Working this expression, will give you an equation like this:

$$t=√(2h/g)$$

And this gives you the time that the ball takes to reach the ground from the initial height.

As you see, $t$ is proportional to $√h$ and we conclude that, the time that it takes will increase as the height also increases.

Hope to help!

Answer (score 0):

Ignoring air resistance, all objects near the Earth's surface fall at the same rate of acceleration, approximately 9.8 meters per second squared, whether of the same mass or not. So, when released at the same time, the object closer to the ground would reach the ground  first.